# Is it possible to serve .aspx files via dotnet core (i.e. Kestrel)?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I have a bunch of simple .aspx files providing simple web pages for testing purposes. I'm running Linux and have no access to a Windows machine.

I could convert the .aspx pages into something else (NodeJS using Express, perhaps) but I risk altering the logic through mistakes as I make this conversion. This is my fallback position.

My current goal is to use dotnet core to build an environment into which I can drop each .aspx file (one at a time is fine) and see it running in a webserver as it was intended. I've constructed the base of such an environment via:

```
$ dotnet new -t web
$ dotnet restore
$ dotnet run
```

This gives me a working webserver running a default website on localhost:5000 - great! However I can't get it to execute, or even read, .aspx files; http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico does read the contents of wwwroot/favicon.ico, yet dumping foo.aspx into wwwroot/ and trying out http://localhost:5000/foo.aspx gives a 404 - I was expecting at least a 500 demanding that I configure serving of .aspx, or perhaps a 200 with the literal contents of foo.aspx, but 404? I added a wwwroot/test.txt file with new contents and it serves that just fine as static content.

Thinking I might be able to (ab)use the MVC setup I'd been provided by the default template I set up a new controller FooController, dumped foo.aspx into Views/Foo/Index.cshtml and got the thing executing finally, hacked the .cshtml file so it looked like the other provided .cshtml files (really just replacing <% %> with @{ }) and it still doesn't work because this .aspx file references Request.Form["data"] so I get an error: "The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context".

Am I barking up the wrong tree? I don't have any experience with ASPX or the new MVC infrastructure. My task is to translate code in Java to Python & Ruby that acts against these provided web pages. Can I easily serve the .aspx files on Kestrel or should I fall back to translating the ASPX stuff over to NodeJS?

Please note that suitability for a production environment is not relevant here; this is purely for dev testing and will not be served to the wider internet, or indeed anywhere except localhost.

Comment: Have you considered using Mono?

Comment: @Gusman is there an easy way to serve aspx via mono? I'm ideally looking for a simple embedded solution to fire up in dev, i.e. not neeing to set up Apache for mod_mono.

Comment: Yes, you can use NGINX or even use a self-hosted solution, this may help you: http://uuksu.kapsi.fi/webapi_selfhosted_on_mono.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>At this point,</strike> ASP.NET Web Forms <strike>are not supported in</strike> will not be supported with .NET Core.

You could easily get a VM with Windows and run it from there.

Comment: I can't easily get a Windows VM without a license, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ahri theres trial license vms out there from microsoft.

Comment: Has this changed? We badly need to move a large aspx asp.net app into .net core. (Converting to razor is out of the question, almost 1000 pages and templates in aspx)

Comment: @Jonesome nope there is not a plan AFAIK.

Comment: @DanielA.White, if we use .NET framework 4.7.2 with ASP.NET Core could we host Web Forms within the same site?

Comment: @VAUser1 nope. There’s too many things that depends on Windows in classic ASP.net

Comment: @DanielA.White is it possible to serve an aspx page if my asp.net core site runs on IIS or Azure???

Comment: @CryingFreeman it depends on what is your hosting infrastructure. are you hosting on the .net core runtime or the .net framework runtime.

Comment: @DanielA.White on  .net framework runtime because I relay on a library that depends on full .net Framework

Comment: I have a situation where some users can create .aspx scripts and then paste on the ASP.NET app in IIS server to run it. I rewired the app to use ASP.NET Core that does not know .aspx files. Is there any way to execute .aspx files inside the scope of the ASP.NET core app?

Comment: @CryingFreeman only if it’s running on the framework version of .net

Answer (score 1):

I've been asking myself the same question for years now!  Why not?  When we first had ASP.NET MVC, we were told it was built on top of ASP.NET, and therefore shared common ground with ASPX pages - and indeed is possible to deliver both in an .NET Framework project.
However, when .NET Core came along (now just .NET) Pure MVC concepts were re-engineered.  This means there is a clear upgrade path from .NET Framework's MVC to .NET Core's MVC.  That is, ONLY the pure MVC pattern with views and partial views.

Therefore, to stick with .NET technologies you have little choice but to translate the pages into something newer.  Microsoft themselves recommend ASPX pages be upgraded to not just MVC, but Blazor pages.  I can understand why, I advocate the same.  But MVC is possible too.

[article with download ebook.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/migrate-web-forms)

Things like reading from the Request as you mention only translates to HTTP POST/PUT  in an MVC controller, which means you then need to think in terms of a Model to pass on to your View.  With single pages translating to this pattern, you can make the transition to MVC under .NET (core) relatively easily.

However, the standard (bad) practice adopted by many, is to hack away in the ASPX page or the code behind file, without clear separation of concerns.  This doesn't translate well to MVC.

Blazor on the other hand, not requiring a view model, means you're free to abuse page level variables (global variables) all you like.  That's not to say its good practice, but it does mean you can pick up on the http request data (have that dependency injected into your component) and therefore there is likely to be less re-development, and it becomes more like refactoring, unlike the MVC upgrade.

So, yeah, Blazor is an easier path forwards if you just want the end-result.  But if you want maintainability, I'd really think about correcting that hacky code, and introduce proper separation of concerns.  But the same could also be said for an MVC solution.

Therefore, if you're familiar with MVC already, then this might be the least path of resistance for you, even though Microsoft advocate Blazor.

Here's a link to an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/migration) that has a downloadable [ebook(pdf)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/e-book/blazor-for-web-forms-devs/pdf) on the subject.

I hope this helps.